# Print listdir items on new line – getting None

Tags: python, python-2.7, listdir

I have this piece of code:

```
import os

def listdir(path):
    print(os.listdir(path))
    print '\n'.join(os.listdir(path))
```

which returns

```
['.idea', 'commands', 'testfile.py', '__pycache__']
.idea
commands
testfile.py
__pycache__
None
```

I do not understand why I get None value on the last line?
Thank for any advice.

Comment: How are you calling `listdir`?

Comment: Why are you using `print()` as a function on the first line? In Python 2, `print` is a statement. You are almost certainly calling `listdir()` with another `print` statement: `print listdir(somepath)`; don't do this, as your `listdir()` function returns `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `listdir`, are you trying to print its return value?

```
print listdir(path)
```

`listdir` doesn't return a value, so if you did that the `print` statement will print `None`. Leave out that `print`:

```
listdir(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no return statement, the function implicitly returns `None`.

```
>>> def func():
...     2013 # no value is being returned
...
>>> func()
>>> func() is None
True

>>> def func():
...     return 2013
...
>>> func()
2013
```